# Any suggestions on how i can create an email link in a java button

Tags: java

What i want to do is create an email link in a button such that when a user clicks the button it fires up default email client with my email address being the destination

I tried experimenting with this but no luck (I have no idea):

```
private void jButton50ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          

    URL url = new URL('tcod@live.ca');
}
```

But of course thats not a URL!

Update: I tried this and i'm getting errors whenever I try to use mail(). Do i have to import something else

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    String mailTo = jButton2.getText();
    URI uriMailTo = null;

    try
    {
        if(mailTo.length() > 0)
        {
            uriMailTo = new URI("mailto", mailTo, null);
            desktop.mail(uriMailTo);
        }

        else
        {
            desktop.mail();
        }
    }

    catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    catch(URISyntaxException use)
    {
        use.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [How to Integrate with the Desktop Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/desktop.html)

This is an example taken directly from the above linked tutorial...

```
private void onLaunchMail(ActionEvent evt) {
    String mailTo = txtMailTo.getText();
    URI uriMailTo = null;
    try {
        if (mailTo.length() > 0) {
            uriMailTo = new URI("mailto", mailTo, null);
            desktop.mail(uriMailTo);
        } else {
            desktop.mail();
        }
    } catch(IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    } catch(URISyntaxException use) {
        use.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

You should also take a look at [`Desktop#mail(URI)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#mail%28java.net.URI%29), taking not of the required format of the `URI`

> A mailto: URI can specify message fields including "to", "cc", "subject", "body", etc. See [The mailto URL scheme (RFC 2368)](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2368.txt) for the mailto: URI specification details.

**Updated with working example...**

```
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

public class TestEmail {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
            Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
            if (desktop.isSupported(Desktop.Action.MAIL)) {
                String mailTo = "sendto@somwhere.com";
                URI uriMailTo = null;
                try {
                    if (mailTo.length() > 0) {
                        System.out.println("Mail to " + mailTo);
                        uriMailTo = new URI("mailto", mailTo,  "This is a message");
                        desktop.mail(uriMailTo);
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Mail");
                        desktop.mail();
                    }
                } catch (IOException ioe) {
                    ioe.printStackTrace();
                } catch (URISyntaxException use) {
                    use.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I kind of understand the whole concept but i tried to use the code but no luck! Here's what i tried (update)